# Javascript/PHP apostrophe Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The following code produces a javascript error when the title contains an apostrophe. I thought I was correctly sanitizing the title field with htmlentities but I still get a javascript error when the title contains an single quote.

How should I correctly sanitize this string to make the function work if the title contains an apostrophe?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_modal_now(id,title,e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#someid').val(id);
    $('#anotherid').val(title);
    $('#yetanotherid').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<?php foreach($item as $k => $v){ ?>
<a onClick="open_modal_now(<?= $v['id']; ?>,'<?= htmlentities($v['title'],ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8"); ?>',event);">Open Modal</a>
<?php } ?>
```

I added the foreach loop that the `<a>` is inside. That might help explain why this info is in an attribute tag.

Comment: Don't embed JS code created by PHP. At very least serialize the value to JSON and use that with `JSON.parse()`. Consider using a webservice.

Comment: Possibly like this?
`<?= json_encode($title); ?>`

Comment: htmlentities is beyond USELESS for building Javascript... it's for an html target only. you need to use json_encode() instead.

Comment: Use [addslashes](http://ua1.php.net/addslashes) instead of htmlentities.

Comment: Brandon - more or less. I would put it somewhere else, not in the attribute, because json_encode can contain `"` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using addslashes solution provided by Eugene Glova, as Marc B stated the htmlentities is not the correct tool for this job.

Corrected Code that works:

```
<?php foreach($item as $k => $v){ ?>
<a onClick="open_modal_now(<?= $v['id']; ?>,'<?= addslashes($v['title']); ?>',event);">Open Modal</a>
<?php } ?>
```